# Replace bracket (][) by ',' in Node JS

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using Node JS and a library replace-in-file

I'm using some functions into a file (functions.js)

And using another file for call function (index.js)

When I launch the script first time it works but then I relaunch the script and the '][' is not replace by ','

Function.js

```
var priority = "";
var expectedValue = "";
var score1 = "";
var score2 = "";

/* some function*/

function generateJSON(key){
    var table = []


    table.push({"executionDate":date,
    "issueID":key,
    "priority":{
        "jira": priority, 
        "computed":score1
    },
    "expectedValue":{
        "jira": expected, 
        "computed":score2
    }
})

var json = JSON.stringify(table,null, 2);

fs.appendFile('templateLog1.json', json, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err)

});

}

function replaceCaracter(){
    const options = {
        files: 'templateLog1.json',
        from: '][',
        to: ',',
    };

    replace(options, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
        return console.error('Error occurred:', error);
        }
        console.log('Replacement results:', results);
    });
}
```

Index.js

```
setTimeout(function() {
    functions.getAllIssueForSCII().then(function(json){
        for (let i=0; i<json.issues.length;i++){
            functions.generateJSON(json.issues[i].key);
            functions.replaceCaracter()
        }

    });
}, 1000)
```

Actual result :

```
[
{
    "executionDate": 1556197884153,
    "issueID": "SCII-10",
    "priority": {
    "jira": "Lowest",
    "computed": -25
    },
    "expectedValue": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    }
}
,
{
    "executionDate": 1556197884153,
    "issueID": "SCII-7",
    "priority": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    },
    "expectedValue": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    }
}
][
{
    "executionDate": 1556197896877,
    "issueID": "SCII-10",
    "priority": {
    "jira": "Lowest",
    "computed": -25
    },
    "expectedValue": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    }
}
][
{
    "executionDate": 1556197896877,
    "issueID": "SCII-7",
    "priority": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    },
    "expectedValue": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    }
}
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
{
    "executionDate": 1556197884153,
    "issueID": "SCII-10",
    "priority": {
    "jira": "Lowest",
    "computed": -25
    },
    "expectedValue": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    }
}
,
{
    "executionDate": 1556197884153,
    "issueID": "SCII-7",
    "priority": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    },
    "expectedValue": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    }
}
,
{
    "executionDate": 1556197896877,
    "issueID": "SCII-10",
    "priority": {
    "jira": "Lowest",
    "computed": -25
    },
    "expectedValue": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    }
}
,
{
    "executionDate": 1556197896877,
    "issueID": "SCII-7",
    "priority": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    },
    "expectedValue": {
    "jira": "Low",
    "computed": -10
    }
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake. As you can see, the first occurence of `][` has indeed been replaced.

This usually happens when you use the `String.replace()` methos with a simple string as the first parameter (the string to replace).

What you need to do is use a regex with the `global` flag. Try changing `']['` to `/]\[/g` in the `options` object.

More details on the `String.replace` method : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Yes Thanks you very much
I just put g at the end ;) 
/]\[/g

Comment: My bad, I indeed made a typo with typing the regex, good catch !